# dropdown select as ID and pass to action class but in search query i have given if null then search all content . how can i search by dropdown ID?

Tags: java, mysql, ajax, dropdown

```
    function searchContentDisplay(key)
    {
       var paramTypeID=$("#ParamList").val();
       var paramValue = document.getElementById("paramVal").value;
        alert(paramValue+paramTypeID);
        $("#ajax_loader").show('slow');
        $.ajax({
            url : "SerachGlobalParam",
            type : "post",
            data : 'globalParamDTO.paramTypeID='+paramTypeID+'&globalParamDTO.paramValue='+paramValue,
            async : true,
            cache : false,
            mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
             beforeSend: function(){
                 $("#ajax_loader").show('slow');
                },
             complete: function(){
                    $("#ajax_loader").hide('slow');
                },
            success : function (data) {
            $("#searchGlobalParam").html(data);

            }
            });
        }
```

I want to search content on select dropdown and id will pass to ajax. if i Dont select any value from dropdown search all content list .The query is working fine when on mysql I have taken null as to select empty dropdown and serach all content but when we pass selected dropdown on ajax it will work for id .if i select nothing then 0 will pass on ajax and travel to action class as 0 only but in my query i have given if null than serach all content .It seems problem between null and 0.

I have set if paramtypeID == 0 than paramTypeID= null then null will travel to action class but it will not execute while.next statement as I dont know why it is not working.try {
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SLCMQueryConstant.SEARCH_GLOBAL_PARAM);

```
        pstmt.setString(1,globalParamDTO.getParamTypeID());
        System.out.println(globalParamDTO.getParamTypeID());
        pstmt.setString(2, globalParamDTO.getParamValue());
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            GlobalParamDTO globalParamDto= new GlobalParamDTO();
            globalParamDto.setParamValue(rs.getString("Value"));
            globalParamDto.setParamTypeName(rs.getString("Param_Type_Name"));
            paramList.add(globalParamDto);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: I have set if paramtypeID == 0 than paramTypeID= null